# Allow to remove product automatically added from cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

In Woocommerce, I am using [this official code snippet](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automatically-add-product-to-cart-on-visit/) to automatically add a to cart a product when customer visit my website:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 1234; //replace with your own product id
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine and adds the product to cart.

But I want the customers to provide the option **to remove this item from cart** if they don't want it. But actually the product cannot be removed.

How can I make the product auto added to cart removable?

Comment: this product is static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin()  && !is_cart() && !is_checkout()) {
        $product_id = 1234; //replace with your own product id
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: Actually when I move to other pages and then come to the cart or checkout page again, then the product is automatically added again. Do you think we should use some sort or session or cookie if the product is removed once?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to update the code please?

Comment: it will take sometimes to investigate